# How to change the value of an argument in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried the following small simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1="bar"
echo $1
```

But when I run `./script foo` I get error and the value is not changed:

```
/home/mika/script: line 2: foo=bar: command not found
foo
```

I know $1 is the first argument you pass to your script. But even like this I want to change its value.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827690/how-to-change-a-command-line-argument-in-bash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the builtin `set`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- "bar"
echo $1
```

Source and more about: [Change a command line argument - bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4827690/2353900).

Comment: I tried that, but it still echoed "foo".  Did you get different results?  Be sure to pass "foo" to the script.

Comment: @MartyFried Ups, sorry... I just update my answer.

Comment: That works. :-)  Good answer... I think I was assuming he didn't want to do that, and I'm not sure why he would, but your answer is actually more correct than my suggestion to simply not do it.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: This removes all other arguments after `$1` if `set -- "bar" "${@:2}"` is not used.

Comment: I needed some additional help to set multiple arguments, not just one, so I wrote [an explanatory and more-thorough answer on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76081159/4561887), in addition to [my short answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464749/327339). Thanks for your work to get me started.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change those variables directly.  You could say:

```
x=$1
echo $x
```

Then you can use `$x` instead

Using `$1=bar` will immediately substitute the first parameter for `$1`, and you are essentially stating `"foo=bar"`, and it is interpreted as a command "foo", not a variable "foo";

Comment: Nice idea, but depend what exactly want the OP to accomplish... +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use use `$1` for this, in `bash`, and other shells, `$1` is the first argument you pass to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

If you run the above as `foo.sh hello`, it will print `hello` since that is the 1st argument. Also, you refer to a variable as `var` and to a variable's *contents* as `$var`. So, to get the behavior you are expecting, just use another name for your variable and don't use a `$`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="bar"
echo $var
```

Comment: This small script was just an example to make people understand what I want. I know $1 is the first argument you pass to your script. But, even like this I want to change its value. I need to apply this in another big script. Thank you.

Comment: @user258266 don't. Just call the big script with the new value, don't use `$1` for values that you want to change. Anyway, as long as you fix the syntax error, it should work, you main  problem was that you were using the `$`.

Comment: But I need... I can't explain here why... Maybe I'll edit my question.

Comment: @user258266 please do. You are trying to set a variable as `$foo="bar"`, that doesn't work, you need `foo="bar"` without the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the [main answer by @Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/a/441222/327339), you can set multiple arguments at once like this:

```bash
# set arguments `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` to these respective values
set -- "one" "two" "three"
echo "$1 $2 $3"
```

Output:

```
one two three
```

### See also

1. My longer answer on Stack Overflow here: [How to change command-line arguments `$1`, `$2`, etc. in bash using `set --`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76081159/4561887)

   1. I go much further and explain much more, including using bash array slicing to retain original arguments before and after the arguments you are changing. Check it out to learn much more.